# Binding a TreeView with ContextMenu in Xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, treeview, contextmenu

I'm pretty new to Xaml and need some advise.

A TreeView should be bound to a hierarchical object structure. The TreeView should have a context menu, which is specific for each object type.

I've tried the following:

```
<TreeView>
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RoomTemplate">
      <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}">
        <TreeViewItem.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Open" />
            <MenuItem Header="Remove" />
          </ContextMenu>
        </TreeViewItem.ContextMenu>
      </TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>

  <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}" Name="tviRoot" IsExpanded="True" >

  <TreeViewItem Header="Rooms"  
                ItemsSource="{Binding Rooms}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RoomTemplate}">
    <TreeViewItem.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Add room"></MenuItem>
      </ContextMenu>
    </TreeViewItem.ContextMenu>
  </TreeViewItem>
</TreeViewItem>
```

But with this markup the behavior is as intended, but the child items (the rooms) are indented too much.

Anyway all the bining samples I could find use TextBlock instead of TreeViewItem in the DataTemplate, but wonder how to integrate the ContextMenu there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would not normally create a DataTemplate containing a TreeViewItem, because the binding infrastructure will be creating the TreeViewItem for you -- all your DataTemplate needs to do is specify what should be displayed as the *content* of the TreeViewItem.  That's why the samples you've found use TextBlocks instead of TreeViewItems in the DataTemplate.

I suspect the use of TreeViewItem rather than TextBlock causes the excessive indenting because you have a (manually created) TreeViewItem in your DataTemplate (which incurs one level of indent) inside another (automatic) TreeViewItem (which incurs another level of indent).  Therefore, using a TextBlock instead of a TreeViewItem should cure this.  Integrating the ContextMenu shouldn't be an issue because TextBlock has a ContextMenu property too.

So you should be able to just change your DataTemplate as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RoomTemplate">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Open" />
        <MenuItem Header="Remove" />
      </ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
  </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Incidentally for TreeViews it is common to use a HierarchicalDataTemplate rather than a plain DataTemplate because this allows for multiple levels of items via the HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource property.  This may not be required in your scenario though.

Comment: Great, that did it! 
I'm using the HierarchicalDataTemplate too. But how do I add some fixed (non-bound) child items to the data bound item template? Like
>Rooms
>>Room1
>>>Windows
>>>>Window1
>>>Doors
where only Room1 and Window1 are data bound?

Comment: So you want to interpose additional fixed nodes?  I *think* you could do that by going back to the TreeViewItem approach: your data template would be a TreeViewItem with the fixed header, whose ItemsSource was bound to the HDT's context e.g. `<HDT><TreeViewItem Header="Rooms" ItemsSource="{Binding}" /></HDT>`.  Not tested though!  If this doesn't work, you might want to post it as a new question as this will probably get more attention and therefore better answers than further discussion in a comment chain -- just a suggestion!

Comment: Nope, that doesn't do it. I'll post a new question.