# TreeView binding issue in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

Consider the following data structure:

```
List<Person> People;
class Person { 
  List<Car> Cars; 
  List<Hobby> Hobbies;
}
```

I want to bind a TreeView to this structure. And it should look like this:

```
People
> Frank
  > Cars
    > BMW
    > Ford
  > Hobbies
    > Tennis
    > Golf
> Jane
  > Cars
  > Hobbies
```

How can this be achieved in XAML? Here's what I've got so far:

```
<TreeView>
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PersonTemplate">
      <TextBlock Header="{Binding Name}">
        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Remove" />
          </ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
      </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>

  <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}"IsExpanded="True" >
    <TreeViewItem Header="People" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PersonTemplate}">
    </TreeViewItem>
  </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

This is a follow up question to [binding-a-treeview-with-contextmenu-in-xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496250/binding-a-treeview-with-contextmenu-in-xaml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a great way to get started using MVVM for treeview binding:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx

Comment: You beat me to it :-) This is such a clean abstraction of presentation and data(Model)-layer. I've actually used Josh's example in production code and it works beautifully.

Comment: I agree, working through this specific sample really made everything click for me.

Comment: Ok, this looks interesting. I'm going to do some further reading tomorrow. 
Are you recommending to use a ViewModel like: class PersonViewModel { object[] Items = { new CarsViewModel(), new HobbiesViewModel() } ? Thus creating a ViewModel for every TreeViewItem I want to display?